# Counting integer points inside a sphere of radius R and dimension D

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to write an efficient algorithm that counts the number of points inside a Sphere of Radius R and Dimension D. The sphere is always at the origin. Suppose we have a sphere of dimension 2 (circle) with radius 5.

My strategy is to generate all possible points within the first quadrant, so for the above example we know that (1,2) is in the circle, so must all + / -  combinations of that point which is simply dimension squared. So for each point found in a single quadrant of an n-dimensional sphere we add 2 ^ dimension to the total count.

I'm not sure if there is a much more efficient solution to this problem but this is what I have so far in terms of implementation.

```
int count_lattice_points(const double radius, const int dimension) {
int R = static_cast<int>(radius);

int count  = 0;

std::vector<int> points;
std::vector<int> point;

for(int i = 0; i <= R; i++)
    points.push_back(i);

do {
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension - 1; i++)
        point.push_back(points.at(i));

    if(isPointWithinSphere(point, radius)) count += std::pow(2,dimension);
    point.clear();

}while(std::next_permutation(points.begin(), points.end()));

return count + 3;
}
```

What can I fix or improve in this situation ?

Comment: Are you assuming it's origin is always at (0, 0) or (0, 0, 0)? It doesn't seem like your current reasoning works without that constraint.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Yes, the sphere is always at the Origin

Comment: The output of the code snippet does not give the expected results for two dimensions, see [The On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A000328).  I see some problems. A point should have as my coordinates as `dimension`, but `i < dimension - 1` in the second `for` loop causes there to be one too few coordinates in the points tested. Adding 2^dimension is incorrect when some of the coordinates are zero since +/- of zero are just zero. It should be 2^(the number of positive coordinates). Also, I don't understand how a point like (1,1) will be counted if just permuting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presented my algorithm for 2D here (with some source code and an ugly but handy illustration):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42373448/5298879

It's around 3.4x faster than [MBo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37405804/5298879) counting points between the origin and the edge of the circle in one of the quarters.

You just imagine an inscribed square and count only one-eighth of what's outside that square inside that circle.

```java
public static int gaussCircleProblem(int radius) {
    int allPoints=0; //holds the sum of points
    double y=0; //will hold the precise y coordinate of a point on the circle edge for a given x coordinate.
    long inscribedSquare=(long) Math.sqrt(radius*radius/2); //the length of the side of an inscribed square in the upper right quarter of the circle
    int x=(int)inscribedSquare; //will hold x coordinate - starts on the edge of the inscribed square
    while(x<=radius){
        allPoints+=(long) y; //returns floor of y, which is initially 0
        x++; //because we need to start behind the inscribed square and move outwards from there
        y=Math.sqrt(radius*radius-x*x); // Pythagorean equation - returns how many points there are vertically between the X axis and the edge of the circle for given x
    }
    allPoints*=8; //because we were counting points in the right half of the upper right corner of that circle, so we had just one-eightth
    allPoints+=(4*inscribedSquare*inscribedSquare); //how many points there are in the inscribed square
    allPoints+=(4*radius+1); //the loop and the inscribed square calculations did not touch the points on the axis and in the center
    return allPoints;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For 2D case this is [Gauss's circle problem.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html)  One possible formula:

```
N(r) = 1 + 4 * r + 4 * Sum[i=1..r]{Floor(Sqrt(r^2-i^2))}
```

(central point + four quadrants, 4*r for points at the axis, others for in-quadrant region).

Note that there is no known simple closed math expression for 2D case.

In general your idea with quadrants, octants etc is right, but checking all the points is too expensive.

One might find the number of ways to compose all squares from 0 to r^2 from 1..D
integer squares *(extension of (4) formula)*.

Note that combinatorics would help to make calculation faster. For example, it is enough to find the number of ways to 
make X^2 from D natural squares, and multiply by 2^D (different sign combinations);  find the number of ways to make X^2 from D-1 natural squares, and multiply by D*2^(D-1) (different sign combinations + D places for zero addend) etc

Example for D=2, R=3

```
addends: 0,1,4,9
possible sum     compositions    number of variants        
0               0+0             1
1               0+1,1+0         2*2=4
2               1+1             4      
4               0+4,4+0         2*2=4
5               1+4,4+1         2*4=8  
8               4+4             4
9               0+9,9+0         2*2=4
-------------------------------------
                                29
```

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example for a same radius and dimension ?

Comment: example for r=5 is too long, r=3 added

Comment: I just have one last request, can you please know what the pseudocode / implementation would look like in terms of R and D ?

Comment: You'll need algorithm for integer partition to known parts (squares), formula for permutations with repetitions. I'd build an array [0..R^2] with possible partitions using dynamic programming to avoid multiple calculations..

Comment: A similar approch, including source code, can be found at
https://monsiterdex.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/integer-lattice-in-n-dimensional-sphere-count-of-points-with-integer-coordinates-using-parallel-programming-part-i/.

The approach consists in finding partitions of the radius, and then for each partition in the sphere compute the number of ways it can be represented in the sphere by both permuting coordinates and flipping the signs of nonzero coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

An approach similar to [that described by MBo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37405804/3982001), including source code, can be found at
https://monsiterdex.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/integer-lattice-in-n-dimensional-sphere-count-of-points-with-integer-coordinates-using-parallel-programming-part-i/.

The approach consists in finding partitions of the radius, and then for each partition in the sphere compute the number of ways it can be represented in the sphere by both permuting coordinates and flipping the signs of nonzero coordinates.

Comment: @BhargavRao, Would it be better that I delete this answer? I understand that it would be better comment to MBo's answer but I cannot do that.

Comment: Nah, Leave it. It looks way better atm. I guess some one must have down voted seeing your initial answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13697450)

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz I couldn't leave a comment at the time of writing. Second the link details a solution much more thoroughly than the answer by [Mbo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37405804/3527268)